# Packages I never knew they existed cause problems

Tags: init-file, debugging, doom, ubuntu

I'm using Kubuntu 22.04 and I tried to configure my doom-emacs Installation. Then I got these weird error-messages and couldn't figure out how to fix them. So I uninstalled doom and emacs completely and normal emacs seems to work fine but when I try to run doom emacs I get them again:
This is the output of doom doctor:

> doom doctor
> The doctor will see you now...
>
> Checking your Emacs version... 
> Checking for Doom's prerequisites...
> Checking for Emacs config conflicts...
> Checking for great Emacs features...
> ! Emacs was not built with native compilation support
> Users will see a substantial performance gain by building Emacs with
> native compilation support, availible in emacs 28+.You must install a
> prebuilt Emacs binary with this included, or compile Emacs with the
> --with-native-compilation option.
> Checking for private config conflicts...
> Checking for stale elc files...
> x There was an unexpected runtime error
> Message: File is missing
> Details: ("Opening directory" "No such file or directory" "/home/user/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.1")
> Backtrace:
> (file-name-all-completions "" "/home/user/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.1")
> (directory-files-recursively "/home/user/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.1" "\.elc$")
> (let ((--dolist-tail-- (directory-files-recursively dir "\.elc$"))) (while --dolist-tail-- (let ((file (car --dolist-tail--))) (if (file-newer-than-file-p (conc...
> (elc-check-dir "/home/user/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.1")
> (let nil (doom-print (doom-print--format "The doctor will see you now...\n")) (doom-print (doom-print--format (doom-print--class 'start "Checking your Emacs vers...
> ((closure (t) (cli alist) (let nil (doom-print (doom-print--format "The doctor will see you now...\n")) (doom-print (doom-print--format (doom-print--class 'start...
> (funcall (closure (t) (cli alist) (let nil (doom-print (doom-print--format "The doctor will see you now...\n")) (doom-print (doom-print--format (doom-print--clas...
> (doom-cli-execute #s(doom-cli ("doom" "doctor") nil (("SUMMARY" . "Diagnoses common issues on your system.") ("MAIN" . "The Doom doctor is essentially one big, s...
> (let ((cli x16) (bindings x17)) (doom-cli-execute cli bindings))
> (let* ((x16 (car-safe x15)) (x17 (cdr-safe x15))) (let ((cli x16) (bindings x17)) (doom-cli-execute cli bindings)))
> (progn (ignore (consp x15)) (let* ((x16 (car-safe x15)) (x17 (cdr-safe x15))) (let ((cli x16) (bindings x17)) (doom-cli-execute cli bindings))))
> (let ((x15 (car --dolist-tail--))) (progn (ignore (consp x15)) (let* ((x16 (car-safe x15)) (x17 (cdr-safe x15))) (let ((cli x16) (bindings x17)) (doom-cli-execut...
> Setting current directory: No such file or directory, /home/user/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.1

And this is the output of doom sync:

> x There was an unexpected runtime error
> Message: Wrong type argument
> Details: (stringp afternoon-theme)
> Backtrace:
> (intern afternoon-theme)
> ((closure ((package . gnu-elpa-mirror) use-package-pre-ensure-function use-package-keywords use-package-ensure-function use-package-defaults package-selected-pac...
> (cl--position gnu-elpa-mirror ((afternoon-theme :url "https://github.com/osener/emacs-afternoon-theme" :ignored-files ("*.png")) (alect-themes :url "https://gith...
>
> (cl-position gnu-elpa-mirror ((afternoon-theme :url "https://github.com/osener/emacs-afternoon-theme" :ignored-files ("*.png")) (alect-themes :url "https://githu...
> (apply cl-position gnu-elpa-mirror ((afternoon-theme :url "https://github.com/osener/emacs-afternoon-theme" :ignored-files ("*.png")) (alect-themes :url "https:/...
>
> (cl-find gnu-elpa-mirror ((afternoon-theme :url "https://github.com/osener/emacs-afternoon-theme" :ignored-files ("*.png")) (alect-themes :url "https://github.co...
> (straight-recipes-nongnu-elpa--translate (cl-find package (straight-recipes-nongnu-elpa--recipes) :key #'(lambda (it) (intern (car it)))))
> (straight-recipes-nongnu-elpa-retrieve gnu-elpa-mirror)
> (apply straight-recipes-nongnu-elpa-retrieve gnu-elpa-mirror)
> (let ((default-directory (if local-repo (straight--repos-dir local-repo) default-directory)) (func (intern (format "straight-recipes-%S-%S" name method)))) (appl...
> (let* ((--cl-rest-- recipe) (local-repo (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- ':local-repo))))) (let ((default-directory (if local-repo (straight--repos-dir local-...
> (let ((recipe (straight--convert-recipe name cause))) (let* ((--cl-rest-- recipe) (local-repo (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- ':local-repo))))) (let ((defaul...
> ! Wrote extended backtrace to ~/.emacs.d/.local/logs/cli.doom.221126091321.15545.error

I tried to find the file where (stringp afternoon-theme) is supposed to be but I didnt't find it in the config files config.el,init.el or packages.el

This is some content of the error file
.emacs.d/.local/logs/cli.doom.221126134605.37527.error:

> ;; -*- lisp-interaction -*-
> ;; vim: set ft=lisp:
> ;; command=("emacs" "--load" "/home/jannis/.emacs.d/bin/doom" "--" "sync" "-up")
> ;; date="2022-11-26 13-46-05"
> ;;;; ENVIRONMENT
> GNU Emacs     v28.1            nil
> Doom core     v3.0.0-pre       grafted, HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD 9d4d5b7 2022-10-31 16:18:16 +0100
> Doom modules  v22.10.0-pre     grafted, HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD 9d4d5b7 2022-10-31 16:18:16 +0100
> ;;;; 0
> ((intern afternoon-theme)
> ((debugger-may-continue . t)
> (inhibit-redisplay)
> (inhibit-debugger . t)
> (inhibit-changing-match-data)))
> ;;;; 1
> (((closure
> ((package . gnu-elpa-mirror)
> use-package-pre-ensure-function use-package-keywords use-package-ensure-function use-package-defaults package-selected-packages package--builtins t)
> (it)
> (intern
> (car it)))
> (afternoon-theme :url "https://github.com/osener/emacs-afternoon-theme" :ignored-files
> ("*.png")))
> ((package . gnu-elpa-mirror)
> (it afternoon-theme :url "https://github.com/osener/emacs-afternoon-theme" :ignored-files
> ("*.png"))))

I can't find any of these lines in any other file

Comment: `(intern afternoon-theme)` is the problem, because `afternoon-theme` didn't have a string value (as `intern` requires a string argument).  I suggest just searching for `afternoon-theme` with `M-x rgrep`.

Comment: I found it only in an error log of emacs
~/.emacs.d/.local/logs/cli.doom.221126133700.36714.error

Comment: Ok.  I know very little about Doom or Straight, and I don't know what's going on there, but hopefully someone else has some insight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was an issue with the latest straight.el commit.

https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/issues/6960

> One way to fix it, is to update straight repo and getting latest
> version of straight , that fixed it for me. it is fixed in straight
> here radian-software/straight.el@3eca39d

> @unuunc Thank you.
>
> Add some details:
>
> `cd ~/.emacs.d/.local/straight/repos/straight.el git pull origin develop`

> You can upgrade if you pin straight first in packages.el
>
> `(package! straight :pin "3eca39d")`

If you don't care about upgrading for now you can skip the unpin in packages.el and just `doom sync`